# {nativescript} get value from datepicker and save result to textbox

Tags: nativescript

On my xml, I have 1 textfield and 1 datepicker. How do I get a datepicker result and storing it result on the textfield?

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
    <TextField hint="tanggalprospek" text="{{ tanggalprospek }}" />
    <DatePicker day="15" month="5" year="2016" id="date" />
    <Button text="Get Tap" tap="{{ getTap }}" />   
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Many thanks for your help.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the datepicker in the page controller and get the date value of it, then set it to the textfield along with the `notifyPropertyChange` event. I also use `moment.js` to have a good date format.

In the xml:

```
<Button text="Get Tap" tap="getTap" />
```

In the page controller:

```
var moment = require("moment");
export function getTap(args) {
    var myDatePicker = page.getViewById("date");
    var date = moment(myDatePicker.date);
    var dateText = date.format("Do MMM [,] H:mm").toString();
    page.bindingContext.set("tanggalprospek", dateText);
    page.bindingContext.notifyPropertyChange("tanggalprospek", dateText);
}
```

P/s: I'm using TypeScript